# Numbered exercises as sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, margins, enumerate

I want to split my document like this

```
Part 1
1)
2)
3)
4)

Part 2
5)
6)
7)
8)
```

How is the best way to do this?

I could use

```
\section{Part 1}
\subsection*{1)
...

\section{Part 2}
\subsection*{5}
...
```

but is this really the best way? I imagine that it makes more sense to use

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item ..
\end{enumerate}
```

for this purpose, but then I can't split it in parts.

I also want the numbers in the left margin, so I don't take up an entire row with just the section header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use a macro `\exercise`.  There you can also internally step a counter for referencing.  The numbers are put in the margin as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{exercise}
\setcounter{exercise}{0}
\newcounter{subexercise}
\setcounter{subexercise}{-1}
\renewcommand\thesubexercise{\arabic{exercise}\alph{subexercise}}%
\newcommand\exercise{%
  \par\noindent
  \ifnum\value{subexercise}>-1
    \refstepcounter{subexercise}%
    \llap{\thesubexercise)\quad}%
  \else
    \refstepcounter{exercise}%
    \llap{\theexercise)\quad}%
  \fi
}
\newenvironment{subexercises}%
  {\refstepcounter{exercise}%
    \setcounter{subexercise}{0}}
  {\setcounter{subexercise}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Part 1}
\exercise\label{ex:1}ABC
\exercise DEF (see Ex.~\ref{ex:1})
\section*{Part 2}
\exercise foo
\begin{subexercises}
  \exercise sub1
  \exercise sub2\label{subex:3b}
  \exercise sub3
\end{subexercises}
\exercise bar (see Ex.~\ref{ex:1} and~\ref{subex:3b})
\begin{subexercises}
  \exercise sub1
  \exercise sub2
  \exercise sub3
\end{subexercises}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to make use of 3a and 3b, etc? So in some of the exercises, it should write 3a) and 3b) instead of 3).

Comment: Thanks :D But I meant without the 3) and 4). So only the subexercises. I really appreciate your help!